# How to get count in mongodb using aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried to get the count of Database using an aggregation query.

**MY Scenrio**

**Access**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    name: 'laptop'
}, {
    "id": 2,
    name: 'deasktop'
}]
```

**Query**

```
db.access.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Exceute the query
**I got the output**

```
[{
    "total": 2
}]
```

**Excepted output**

```
{
    total: 1
    result: [{
        "id": 1,
        name: 'laptop'
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        name: 'deasktop'
    }]
}
```

How to get this output using aggregation query.

Comment: Why is `total` 1 in your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$push` your documents in `$group` stage

```
db.access.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      result: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FARYzGNm-ZE)

**LINK** [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)